# How to combine python asyncio and multiprocessing?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-asyncio

I have a device that needs multiprocessing to handle the CPU bound deserialization & decoding of the incoming data; but the rest of the application is slower IO-limited code, which is excellent for asyncio.  However, it seems like there is no good way to combine multiprocessing and asyncio together.

I have tried https://github.com/dano/aioprocessing, which uses threaded executors for multiprocessing operations.  However, this library does not natively support common asyncio operations; for example, canceling a co-routine waiting on a `queue.get` with this library will lead to deadlock.

I have also tried to use a `ProcessPoolExecutor`, but passing multiprocessing objects to this executor does not work since the queue objects are not passed at the creation of the process.

```
import multiprocessing
import asyncio
import atexit
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor


@atexit.register
def kill_children():
    [p.kill() for p in multiprocessing.active_children()]


async def queue_get(queue: multiprocessing.Queue):
    executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    return await loop.run_in_executor(executor, queue.get)


async def main():
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    get_task = asyncio.create_task(queue_get(queue))

    queue.put(None)

    print(await get_task)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Running this code leads to this exception:

`RuntimeError: Queue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance`

Is there any way to cleanly bridge the gap between multiprocessing and asyncio?

Comment: Do the [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24687061/can-i-somehow-share-an-asynchronous-queue-with-a-subprocess) help? Might be a duplicate

Comment: Yes, that does, thank you @new-dev-123.  I was missing a `multiprocessing.Manager()` to make the code work.

Answer (score 3):

Per [Can I somehow share an asynchronous queue with a subprocess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24687061/can-i-somehow-share-an-asynchronous-queue-with-a-subprocess)

The above code can be modified to work with a multiprocessing queue by creating the queue through a `multiprocessing.Manager()`

```
import multiprocessing
import asyncio
import atexit
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor


@atexit.register
def kill_children():
    [p.kill() for p in multiprocessing.active_children()]


async def queue_get(queue: multiprocessing.Queue):
    executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    return await loop.run_in_executor(executor, queue.get)


async def main():
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    queue = manager.Queue()
    get_task = asyncio.create_task(queue_get(queue))

    queue.put(None)
    print(await get_task)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```