# Selenium / asyncio - using Executor without respawning webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, python-asyncio

I have an `asyncio`-based crawler that occasionally offloads crawling that requires the browser to a ThreadPoolExecutor, as follows:

```
def browserfetch(url):
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    browser.get(url)
    # Some explicit wait stuff that can take up to 20 seconds.
    return browser.page_source

async def fetch(url, loop):
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as pool:
        result = await loop.run_in_executor(pool, browserfetch, url)
    return result
```

My issue is that I believe this respawns the headless browser each time I call `fetch`, which incurs browser startup time on each call to `webdriver.Chrome`. Is there a way for me to refactor `browserfetch` or `fetch` so that the same headless driver can be used on multiple `fetch` calls?

**What have I tried?**

I've considered more explicit use of threads/pools to start the `Chrome` instance in a separate thread/process, communicating within the `fetch` call via queues, pipes, etc (all run in `Executors` to keep the calls from blocking). I'm not sure how to make this work, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that starting browsers in separate processes and communicate with him via queue is a good approach (and more scalable). The **pseudo-code** might look like this:

```
#  worker.py 
def entrypoint(in_queue, out_queue):  # run in process
    crawler = Crawler()
    browser = Browser()
    while not stop:
        command = in_queue.get()
        result = crawler.process(command, browser)
        out_queue.put(result)
```

```
# main.py
import worker

in_queue, out_queue = Process(worker.entrypoint)
while not stop:
    in_queue.put(new_task)
    result = out_queue.get()
```

Comment: `main.py` calls to `put` and `get`: should these be executed in a `pool` to avoid blocking (e.g. `await loop.run_in_executor(None, inqueue.put, new_task)` and `result = await loop.run_in_executor(None, out_queue.get)`), assuming the loop is sitting in a coroutine?

Comment: You can just use repetitive `put_nowait/get_nowait` or leverage some ready classes like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/24704950/13782669